# Overjoining in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server, one which lists Bills of Materials (BoMs):

```
MainPartNo
RequiredPartNo
Quantity
```

and one which lists all serialised assemblies, and any serialised parts :

```
PartNo
SerialNo
Child PartNo
Child SerialNo
```

What I'm trying to do is list all of the BoMs and display a serial number if the child belongs to the parent. I have managed this on one level, but some BoMs call up sub BoMs and I end up with far too many results from my query: If the BoM contains 5 items and there is one Child Serial No, I end up with 5 lines all showing the same Parent and Child

My current query is the following:

```
SELECT
    MainPartNo,
    ParentSerialNo,
    RequiredPartNo,
    ChildSerialNo
FROM 
    BoM_TBL 
LEFT JOIN 
    Serial_TBL on MainPartNo = PartNo
```

This should be a simple `JOIN` but my various permutations have not yet proved successful.

I'm looking to see a list of BoM's for every serialised assembly with `NULL` values in the `ChildSerialNo` column bar where the assembly contains a serialised child.

**EDIT**

Data structure of the tables

**Serial Table**

[image: Serial Table]

**BoM Table**

[image: BoM Table]

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Hi Gordon, I can't post actual data but I'll recreate a sample of the structure and update.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong table here.  Typically a serial number is applied to each individual instance of a part, so in your table with the serial numbers you're going to find the same Part No (or child Part No) many times

Comment: @tomRedox That's correct, I should see many instances of the same Part and Child. The BoM table lists the structure, and the Serial table lists the individual relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outer apply can work...

```
SELECT 
A.MainPartNo,
B.ParentSerialNo,
A.RequiredPartNo,
C.ChildSerialNo
FROM Serial_TBL A
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT DISTINCT ParentSerialNo FROM BoM_TBL WHERE PartNoParent = A.MainPartNo
) B
LEFT JOIN BoM_TBL C on A.MainPartNo = C.PartNoParent AND B.ParentSerialNo = C.ParentSerialNo AND A.RequiredPartNo = C.PartNoChild
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I need. I think I can build from this, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Are you want something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #BoM 
(
    MainPartNo VARCHAR(20),
    RequiredPartNo VARCHAR(20),
    Quantity INT
)

INSERT INTO #BoM (MainPartNo, RequiredPartNo, Quantity)
VALUES ('AssemblyA', 'ChildA', 2), ('AssemblyA', 'ChildA', 2),
       ('AssemblyA', 'ChildB', 2), ('AssemblyA', 'ChildC', 2),
       ('AssemblyA', 'PartA', 1), ('AssemblyA', 'PartB', 2),
       ('AssemblyB', 'ChildA', 2), ('AssemblyB', 'ChildD', 3),
       ('AssemblyB', 'ChildE', 1), ('AssemblyB', 'PartA', 1)

CREATE TABLE #Serial 
(
     ParentSerialNo INT,
     ChildSerialNo INT,
     PartNoChild VARCHAR(20),
     PartNoParent VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Serial (ParentSerialNo, ChildSerialNo, PartNoChild, PartNoParent)
VALUES (5001, 10001, 'ChildA', 'AssemblyA'),
       (5001, 10002, 'ChildA', 'AssemblyA'),
       (5001, 11001, 'ChildB', 'AssemblyA'),
       (5001, 11002, 'ChildB', 'AssemblyA'),
       (5001, 12001, 'ChildC', 'AssemblyA'),
       (5001, 12002, 'ChildC', 'AssemblyA'),
       (5002, 10003, 'ChildA', 'AssemblyB'),
       (5002, 10004, 'ChildA', 'AssemblyB'), 
       (5002, 13001, 'ChildD', 'AssemblyB'),
       (5002, 13002, 'ChildD', 'AssemblyB'),
       (5002, 13003, 'ChildD', 'AssemblyB'),
       (5002, 14001, 'ChildE', 'AssemblyB')


SELECT 
    MainPartNo, 
    ParentSerialNo,
    RequiredPartNo,
    ChildSerialNo
FROM
    #BoM B
FULL JOIN 
    #Serial S ON B.MainPartNo = S.PartNoParent
              AND B.RequiredPartNo = S.PartNoChild
```

But I assume that your BoM table has a column like `MainPortSerialNo`, iIf so then use `MainPortSerialNo` instead of `ParentSerialNo` in the query

Answer (score 0):

Would this deliver what you want (a sample result table would be helpful)?

```
Select

MainPartNo,
aa.serial_tbl as ParentSerialNo,
RequiredPartNo

FROM BoM_TBL 
Outer apply (select top 1 Serial_TBL where MainPartNo = PartNo and childserialno is null) aa
```

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't get this to give me the result I needed.

Comment: No problem - after you updated the question I'd have updated my answer as per Daniels' but he beat me to it!